# Memory leak issue with using device contexts

Tags: python, c++, winapi, memory-leaks

I'm using a combination of python and c++ to create a snapshot of a screen area and use that screenshot as part of a video feed (pixmap in a label PyQt5) as well as save the screenshot as a .bmp.. currently done at 30fps for creating a video file later.  The code works to this degree so far just fine, aside from the memory leak I'm getting.

contextcreator.cpp, put into libccreator.so

```
#include "contextcreator.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <typeinfo>

BYTE* createContext(int x, int y, int width, int height){
    HDC hdesktop = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdesktop);    
    HBITMAP hbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdesktop, width, height);
    HGDIOBJ hbitmapOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, hbitmap);
    BitBlt(memDC, 0, 0, width, height, hdesktop, x, y, SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT);

    SelectObject(memDC, hbitmapOld);

    BITMAPINFO bmi = {0};
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmi.bmiHeader);

    GetDIBits(hdesktop, hbitmap, 0, 0, NULL, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    BYTE* stream = new BYTE[bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    GetDIBits(hdesktop, hbitmap, 0, bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight, (LPVOID)stream, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    BYTE* data = new BYTE[14 + sizeof(bmi) + bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage];
    memcpy(data + 14, &bmi, sizeof(bmi));
    memcpy(&data[0] + sizeof(bmi) + 14, stream, bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);

    for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++){
        data[i] = 0;  }

    delete[] stream;

    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdesktop);
    DeleteDC(memDC);

    return data;
}

void releaseData(BYTE* stream){
    delete[] stream;
}
```

The python code that utilizes libccreator.so

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from ctypes import *
import ctypes.wintypes as wintypes
import time
import os

os.add_dll_directory("C:/msys64/mingw64/bin")

mylib = cdll.LoadLibrary('C:/Users/amish_ac2c1jm/OneDrive/Documents/blahblah/libccreator.so')

create_context = mylib.createContext
create_context.argtypes = [c_int, c_int, c_int, c_int]
create_context.restype = POINTER(wintypes.BYTE)

release_stream = mylib.releaseData
release_stream.argtypes = [POINTER(wintypes.BYTE)]
release_stream.restype = None


class CaptureThread(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    update_image = pyqtSignal([bytearray])

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.stopthread = False
        self.framenumber = 0

    def run(self):
        test_timer = time.time()
        while not self.stopthread:
            if time.time() - test_timer >= 1000/30/1000:
                test_timer = time.time()
                self.capture()
        self.finished.emit()

    def capture(self):
        bmpptr = create_context(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)

        data = bytearray(string_at(addressof(bmpptr.contents) + 0x22, 0x4))
        size = int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='little', signed=False) + 0x36
        data = bytearray(string_at(bmpptr, size))

        release_stream(bmpptr)

        data[0:2] = b'BM'
        value = int.from_bytes(data[0x22:0x26], byteorder='little', signed=False)
        data[2:6] = (value + 0x36).to_bytes(4, byteorder='little', signed=False)
        data[6:10] = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
        data[10:14] = b'\x36\x00\x00\x00'

        with open(f"images/frame{self.framenumber}.bmp", "wb") as f:
            f.write(data)
        self.framenumber += 1

        self.update_image.emit(data)
```

Originally i had some memory leaks from not deleting the byte arrays created with the new keyword, and such memory leak issue was apparent quite quickly when my monitors started blinking and chrome would crash along with pycharm.  I also wasn't originally using ReleaseDC for the [hardware?] DC, but instead using DeleteDC for both that DC and the memory DC.  I was able to visually see the memory leak in task manager as my project very quickly overcame chrome and pycharm memory usage (these bmp's aren't compressed after all.. something I'll look into later).  Still, a memory leak persists but doesn't show up for my app in task manager, only showing my overall memory usage gradually increase until i run out of memory.  Takes about 7min or so (i have 16gb of RAM).

I feel it has something to do with the DC's, but i'm not entirely sure.  I have some experience with c++ from a while back, but once i learned python i didn't miss compiler and linking issues to say the least lol.
I use PyCharm for my python IDE and Qt Creator for c++.  Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Simply don't use raw pointers. Who is going to free the bytes you allocated? There are also a lot of other things that can benefit from more RAII to ensure nothing leaks in case of errors.

Comment: `CreateCompatibleBitmap` is not paired with `DeleteObject`

Comment: For high-performance screen recording you should probably use [`Windows.Graphics.Capture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture) instead. [Robert Mikhayelyan](https://github.com/robmikh/) has put together a full [Win32CaptureSample](https://github.com/robmikh/Win32CaptureSample) application, that illustrates both screen capture as well as video encoding.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik that seems to be the issue, i let it run for several minutes and my overall memory usage never went above 46% but for small moments.  Is their a way for me to mark this as answered?  I'll do more tests before i officially close it, but i feel pretty confident you got me covered.  Also, thank you very much.. i'm a bit mad i didn't just double check the docs across the functions for more cleanup notes.

Comment: You are free to write a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (and to accept it later).

Comment: @IInspectable I came across that when i was already deep into having my current solution to the capture issue.  A brief look just now and i don't see how I capture a portion of the screen/app as opposed to the whole thing.  I currently catch and block mouse events to select an area of the screen to get a region.  I have my app now making video files out of the area, which was the goal (no sound tho lol).  Also, this is hobbyist practice programming while i don't have any projects I truly care about in mind, so overall learning and keeping my code brain sharp.  Anyhow, I appreciate the info. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment response from Igor Tandetnik, the leak was from not deleting the object returned from the CreateCompatibleBitmap function.